# CruiseControl.Net - View report / log of build in progress

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

We have a fairly lengthy build process, and so its nice to be able to see the build output / log of the build while the build is in still in progress.

Is there any way of doing this with CruiseControl.Net / MSBuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way of doing it in CruiseControl.Net. But have you tried [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)? As a long time CC fan, I've just switched to TeamCity (they have a free Professional version which supports 20 configurations and 3 build/test servers).

Continuous build log reporting is one of the really nice features about TeamCity - it even reports the status of Tests as they pass or fail. The other nice thing is the very-much-simpler configuration - no more xml files!

Answer (score 0):

Change the verbosity on the MSBuild execution. Note the /v:normal below.

You'll get lots of detail with that:)

```
<msbuild>
    <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>c:\yada</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>yada.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Release /t:clean /v:normal /p:PlatformTarget=anycpu</buildArgs>
    <logger>C:\CruiseControl.NET\server\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCnet.dll</logger>
    <targets></targets>
    <timeout>$(BuildTimeout)</timeout>
 </msbuild>
```